# Excel multiply number by another number x times

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to multiply a number by another number x times...
e.g. multiply 100 by 2, 3 times is
100 x 2 x 2 x 2 = 800
but I need to do it when 2 is another cell and the number times I multiply by 2 is also a another cell i.e. in this example 3

Comment: Just to add ideally formula not VBA

Answer (score 5):

Refer to the following screenshot and try the formula

```
=(A1*(A2^A3))
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful thank you... had brain freeze :)

Comment: @Arv technically none of the brackets are needed, but it does a great job if you are not aware of order of operations

Answer (score 0):

say the cells are A1, B1 and C1

A1 = 100

B1 = 2

C1 = 3

D1 = Result = (a1*(b1^c1)) *edited

Just a simple maths equation ;)

Comment: simple math but its 2^3 = 8 not 2*3 = 6

Comment: Hi Thanks 
But not quite as the result of the formula you provides is 600 not 800 if you did (((100 x 2) x 2) x 2) and so on depending of the number in the cell of the number of iterations you want to multiply, in this case 3...